# Use my own Android app/apk as launcher/Home Screen Replacement

Tags: java, android, launcher, homescreen

I've created my own app and I want this one to be my launcher. It's a simple app, but it works.

Is it possible to replace the default launcher with my app so that my app always starts by default after booting?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Setting the correct intent filters in your manifest will allow it be prompt you to use it as a replacement:

```
<activity android:name="Home"
            ...
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true">
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

See the [Intents and Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) documentation from Google.

Comment: hello Jon and B770,                                                i have successfully implemented lock screen as home screen replacement app. and i also targeting default home screen after unlocking logic by using setComponentEnabledSetting() . but this is working for me till i unlock once. means if i unlock first time than after not getting custom lock screen.. any help?  thanks...

Comment: @SanketKachhela: The question and answer relate to home screen replacements; not lock screen replacements. You should ask a new Question with the code you have now, what you're seeing and need to solve, etc. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask on how to ask a good question.

Comment: yes.. i implemented as home screen replacement and in unlock logic i disabled this home screen by using setComponentEnableSetting() and in meanifeast i have created activity alias to disable and enable action programetically. but after disabling i am getting only default home screen. any help plz... thanks

Comment: @SanketKachhela: It still sounds like that's another issue. I suggest asking it as a new Question.

Comment: This works flawlessy for me, but I then my home button does nothing oustide the lockscreen. Is this just me?

Comment: how can i do it programmatically . i am creating a screen lock app. it needs to disable the home button . so i need to set my app as the home screen temporarily .

Comment: archive of broken link: https://web.archive.org/web/20120207002203/http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/index.html

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at the home tutorial http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/index.html

Comment: Google pulled this sample code from their documentation

Comment: Please fix link to the archived https://web.archive.org/web/20120207002203/http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/index.html