# When building android system how can i set my app to be the defual app

Tags: android, build

i'm developing an android app.
i have all my apps installed and working.
now i need to set my main app as the defualt app and run it on bootup.

does anyone knows how can i do that?

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call my-dir/src/)

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := BLT

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
```

Comment: The default app? Hmm not sure, have you looked for `/etc/inittab` on the FS? If you don't use that then the user might have to choose "use by default" when selecting from a list of apps registered to handle the content you are opening.

Comment: When you say the default app do you actually mean replacing the home screen application?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possibe without hacks on a rooted phone for security.  Android does not allow an app to set itself as the default without user confirmation.

Comment: i know for sure you can. there is a file name packages.xml located at /date/system, i can change him manualy so that my app will load on startup but whati dont know is how to configure it in the building of the android system.

Comment: That was my point.  This is undocumented, and therefore a hack, and can only be accomplished on a rooted device.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the line:

`LOCAL_OVERRIDES_PACKAGES := Launcher2`

to your Android.mk file, then Launcher2 (the default home screen) will not be included in your final image.  You'll need to fix up your AndroidManifest.xml like so ([Use my own Android app/apk as launcher/Home Screen Replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248213/use-my-own-android-app-apk-as-launcher-home-screen-replacement)), but when you install the image and boot the phone, your app will be the default home screen app.

Hope this helps!