# Custom Lock Screen Delay When Wake

Tags: android, locking, screen, lockscreen

I'm trying to make a custom lock screen app, but I'm not sure if I'm going about it the right way.  I have a broadcast receiver that listens to when the screen is turned on and starts my lock screen activity.  This receiver is registered inside a service, which also disables the default lock screen.

The problem is, there is a slight delay between when the screen is turned on and the lock screen activity shows up.  How would I go about doing it so that it shows up right away?

My code for the service:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    BroadcastReceiver powerReceiver = new PowerReceiver();
    registerReceiver(powerReceiver, filter);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {  

    KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Service.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    lock.disableKeyguard();

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

and the receiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        Intent showScreen = new Intent(context, LockScreen.class);
        showScreen.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(showScreen);


    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn your app into a home screen replacement app and when the user successfully unlocks the custom lock screen you can take them to the default home app.

You can find more info in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248213/use-my-own-android-app-apk-as-launcher-home-screen-replacement) and [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+home+screen+replacement&submit=search) questions.

Comment: Thanks but how do i redirect them to the default homescreen after unlocking?  If i use an implicit intent, then if they set my lock screen as the default homescreen, they would just go back to the lock screen?  I tried intent.setClassName("com.android.launcher", "com.android.launcher2.Launcher"); which just gives me an error

Comment: Already tried that, and it gives me the "complete action using" prompt unless i choose the default.  Does the user have to choose their original homescreen as the default app?  Then how would I get the lock screen to show up in the first place?

Comment: Your lock screen needs to be the default home application. I'm not 100% sure how other people are getting the launchers to show after the unlock of a custom lock screen

Comment: Figured it out!  Gotta disable the manifest intent filter by using setComponentEnabledSetting(), and then turn it back on when the activity pops up.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hey CoffeeCrisp, can you please explain how you accomplished this? I would love to know as well. I also receive a delay between the screen on and activity start.

Comment: @CoffeeCrisp so finally you went ahead with your approach or used the homescreen replacement app?

Comment: @Luke, can you please help me with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089525/understanding-custom-lock-implementation-on-android-via-home-screen-replacement (I'll highly appreciate any help). Thanks.

Comment: @Luke your answer is very helpful. i have make home screen replacement app successfully.. but how can i take user to default home screen(after unlocking)? can you describe more about this. Thank You so much...

Comment: I've never actually implemented it, I would take a look at `setComponentEnabledSetting()`

Comment: hello @CoffeeCrisp i have successfully implemented lock screen as home screen replacement app. and i also targeting default home screen after unlocking logic by using setComponentEnabledSetting() as Luke described . but this is working for me till i unlock once. means if i unlock first time than after not getting custom lock screen.. any help?  thanks...