# How to disable home button of Android device in lollipop

Tags: android, locking, android-homebutton

I want to intercept home button click of Android device in lollipop version.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be done in another style if suits your requirement. By 
creating your activity as home activity. If you want to disable home button 
and show your custom application activity as launcher when home button is
pressed. Just add these lines in manifest for that activity for which you want your launcher.

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.example.TempActivity"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true" >
         <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

if user presses the home button, Android will ask for which launcher you want your home. Then your have to select your application launcher ALWAYS not ONLY ONCE.

if you want fully disable the user, so that he cant move to another screen 
 then set theme to fullscreen with NoTilebar.

Comment: i'm also facing same problem but onAttachedToWindow() method cant be override. it show error.....please check it.

Comment: sorry mayuri i have already try this code but not work for me you can visit my problem ..... if you have any soloution and you want , i can mail my code to you. please see this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29920762/how-to-override-the-home-key-function

Comment: what is exactly problem...for disable home button it ll work..show your stacktrace or any bug?

Comment: i want develop a screen lock app like pattern lock. so i want disable home key until unlock screen.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
};
```