# HOME/LAUNCHER activity messes up activity stack

Tags: android, android-intent, launcher

We are developing a home screen replacement app (a kind of launcher), so our home activity is defined as follows:

```
<activity android:name="Home"
        ...
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

(see [Use my own Android app/apk as launcher/Home Screen Replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248213/use-my-own-android-app-apk-as-launcher-home-screen-replacement))

This works great, except for the following scenario:

- User is in Home activity
- User presses a button to go to activity A
- User presses the **home button** (hardware device button), so Home activity is shown again
- User presses a button to go to activity B
- User presses the back button

At this point, activity A is shown again.

**However, I expect the application to show the home activity.** After all, the user went from the home activity to activity B.

What are we doing wrong?

Comment: post the functionality of home button

Comment: How to do that? The home button is standard Android functionality..

Comment: what do you mean with home button ? hardware device button or a button in UI that redirects the user to home activity of your application ?

Comment: I mean the hardware device button. It leads the user back to our Home activity, since it is the one registered as the device home screen (launcher)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching to `android:launchMode="singleTask"` solved the problem.