# Customizing Glass

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I need to customize Glass such that only the kernel and the window manager are present. In addition, when Glass boots, it needs to simply bring up our Android application.

Fortunately, Google team has graciously provided basic instructions for rooting Glass at https://developers.google.com/glass/tools-downloads/system. Understandably, rooting Glass will void your warranty. This is okay for us.

There are also instructions on how to build the kernel for Glass.

However, for our needs, I am thinking I don't even need to worry about rebuilding the kernel. I think all I need is to just modify init.rc, comment out the loading of unneeded application and add my application to the list. I am assuming there is an init.rc file as Android is based on Linux.

I would appreciate it if someone can point me in the right direction. Is modifying init.rc good enough or something else is required? Or, do I really have to build a custom kernel? Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One good way to start around would be to check the tutorials about how to extract and repack system.img file.

https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20extract%20system.img

Options in this search would point out to a certain direction. 
This will let you customize your own Glass image, remove/add system APKs, etc.
Doing this, you should also be able to remove the GlassHome.apk to remove the default launcher.

And because you want specific features when the Glass boots you can try to add your own launcher, you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248213/use-my-own-android-app-apk-as-launcher-home-screen-replacement) guide in order to achieve this:

Hope this would Help!!