# Detect if app has been minimized android

Tags: android

I want to detect when my app minimizes by the hardware minimize button or code and launch itself again when minimized, i'm using the following code but it does nothing. I think it launches itself but in background.

```
@Override
    protected void onUserLeaveHint() 
   { 
     launchApp();
        System.out.println("Home Button Pressed");
        super.onUserLeaveHint();
    }
```

i am calling my intent from the launchApp() method

Comment: You can't force the device to run your app in front. However, you can override onPause nor onStop to perform background stuff before it's minimized/closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Application.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks()** (API >= 14) as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29999738/3522053) to execute code if your app goes in the background and is not resumed within a time limit.

However, for most apps you should not need to do this and there might be a better way to achieve what you need - can you explain your use case?

For example, if you need to process long running tasks even when the app is not visible, you could use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html). Or if you are building an app that is meant to be always visible for some demo purposes, you could set it as a [custom launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8250581/3522053).